# Smale's relative h-cobordism theorem

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds

In Smale's *On the structure of manifolds* paper there is his relative version of the h-cobordism theorem, specifically Theorem 3.1 (and 1.4).  Roughly speaking this concerns the situation where one has an h-cobordism of pairs, and you want some compatibility between the ambient product structure and the submanifold product structure.

I find I don't think about this theorem often, but every once and a while I do need to use it. Each time I return to it, I take considerable time to process how it can be used -- somehow it is not worded in a way that plays well with my way of thinking about things. . . and there are a few distracting typos.

I imagine I am not the only person with this problem.

Are there other expositions of the relative h-cobordism theorem in the literature?

Comment: Here is a probably useless remark: Cor. 3.2 of the paper ought to follow from a space level statement.  Given a compact submanifold $T\subset M$ of codimension zero which is a thickening of a positive codimensional submanifold $V\subset M$, there is a relative h-cobordism space $H(M,T)$. It ought to sit in a fiber sequence $CE(T,M) \to H(M,\text{rel} T) \to H(M)$, where $\text{CE}$ refers to concordance embeddings.  When enough simple connectivity is around, both  $CE(T,M)$ and $H(M)$ are connected (by the h-cobordism thm), implying that $H(M,T)$ will also be connected.